# Counter in while-loop only adds once? - Python

Tags: python, while-loop, increment

I want to count the number of comparisons from insertion sort but the count variable isnt incremented like it should be. It should give around (n*(n-1))/2  (n is the size of the array) but it gives me n/2 instead.

```
#---------------InsertionSort----------------#
def insertion_sort(a):
    count = 0                   #<----
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        current = a[i]
        k = i
        while k>0:        
            count = count+1     #<----
            if current<a[k-1]:
                a[k] = a[k-1]
                k = k-1
            else:
                break
        a[k] = current
    return count
```

I tried using global variables, declare variables as nonlocal, split the counting into one counter for the for-loop and one for the while-loop. Nothing works

update:
here is how i produce the arrays

```
for N in range(1,100):
    quick_sort_x.append(N)
    insertion_sort_x.append(N)
    comparisons_qs = 0
    comparisons_is = 0
    for i in range(5): 
        a = list(range(N)) 
        random.shuffle(a) 
        b = a
        comparisons_qs += quick_sort(a)
        comparisons_is += insertion_sort(b)

    comparisons_qs = comparisons_qs/5
    comparisons_is = comparisons_is/5
```

Comment: What array do you give to try ?

Comment: An array of numbers. And moving the count to inside if didnt help either

Comment: no kidding .. Could give an example of input, the output and the expected output ?

Comment: well, they are randomized:

Comment: also, the algorithms themself work fine

Comment: My guess from the amount of code we have here is that you're only going through the loop once and hitting your "else" block, which breaks the loop.

Comment: Randomized? You are testing it wrong, then. You should run this on a single, specific example, that produces the worst-case behavior. Something like `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` will work nicely. You will see that the function there returns `10`. It is counting fine, your random lists just are partially sorted, most likely, and do not trigger the worst case behavior.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, but it would be surprising since I sorted like 2000 algorithms

Comment: WELP I found the problem: When I sort the array a with quicksort, then b will be sorted too, therefore the weird counting. Thanks!

Comment: Stepping through your code is a good exercise to check that it is doing what you expect it to do. Try PythonTutor.com or a debugger in VSCode or PyCharm.